# Why doesn't this switch to different colors?

Tags: javascript, html

I had a problem where I couldn't get my banner to change its color from something stored in sessionStorage. I fixed that, but there's a bug where if you have never changed the theme, nothing would be in the sessionStorage, so the banner set all colors to black. I fixed it so that the banner is now the default color on load, but it won't change anymore.

I've tried multiple different arguments for the if statement

Here's the detecting code:

```html
function checkBanner() {
  var textColor = sessionStorage.getItem('textColor');
  var backgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('bgColor');

  /*
  Sets color when you've never switched the theme before, but doesn't switch when you switch the theme
  |
  |
  v

  */
  if (sessionStorage.textColor !== 'black' || 'white') {
    var textColor = 'black';
    document.getElementById('banner').style.color = textColor;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.color = textColor;
  }

  if (sessionStorage.bgColor !== 'red' || 'purple') {
    var backgroundColor = 'red';
    document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  }
}

checkBanner();
```

Here's the toggle switch code:

```html
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to switch on light mode? (It hurts my eyes)");
    if (r == true) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
      sessionStorage.setItem('bgColor', 'purple');
      sessionStorage.setItem('textColor', 'white');
      document.getElementById('banner').src = document.getElementById('banner').src

    } else {
      toggleSwitch.checked = false;
    }
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
    sessionStorage.setItem('textColor', 'black');
    sessionStorage.setItem('bgColor', 'red');
    document.getElementById('banner').src = document.getElementById('banner').src
  }
}
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
if (currentTheme) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
  if (currentTheme === 'light') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
  }
}
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

The banner automatically refreshes when you change the theme, so thats not a problem. It should automatically be red background and black text on load of website, but it should change when you change the theme.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle of the above code so we can review it, especially the html would be helpful and the css.

Comment: @CalvinNunes `sessionStorage.x` is the same as `sessionStorage.getItem('x')`

Comment: Agreeing with @CalvinNunes, Javascript does not work the same way some languages work. Javascript reads `if (sessionStorage.textColor !== 'black' || 'white')` as, if sessionStorage.textColor does not equal "black", or "white" is not a true statement, then:...

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I never saw this usage and didn't know. thanks for the info

Comment: It was sessionStorage.getItem('x') when I was testing it (i forgot to change it back to that) but not the second thing. I'll try that

Comment: Also, `document.getElementById('banner').src = document.getElementById('banner').src` is COMPLETELY useless... Any explanation behind this? You are setting something equal to itself...

Comment: That is for reloading the banner every time you toggle the theme

Comment: @TabulateJarl8 Well it reloads automatically when you change it, right? Or is there some part of code not shown preventing it from doing that?

Comment: Please, include some HTML to turn this code into a [mcve]... right now, I see many problems with the JS logic, but I need some html to confirm and try to help/fix

Comment: I added the code and it didn't work. Would it be fine if i put a repl instead of a jsfiddle so i can have multiple files?

Comment: Here's the link if u want to debug: https://repl.it/join/snphvxgq-tabulate

Comment: Can it be  that some other CSS rules avoid any changes ? Would not be the first times that the JS code was ok but nothing happens.

Comment: It was changing, but then my friend (we run the website together) found the bug where if you have never visited before, it wont have any color on load

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it. I just set the default values in CSS and then alter it afterwards. Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
<style>
    a:link{
    color: white;   
    }
    a:visited{
    color: white;   
    }

    .banner {
background-color: red;
color: black;
}



        </style>


    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="banner" class="banner" style="border:2px dotted orange; height:20px; width:100%; "><center>Check out our <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4Eg3V26uXxWY-M639mGDrQ" target="_blank">Youtube</a> Channel! &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Help reinstate Net Neutrality! Visit <a href="https://www.battleforthenet.com/" target="_blank">https://www.battleforthenet.com/</a>!!<center></div>

            </body>   

            <script>
                function checkBanner() {
                    var textColor = sessionStorage.getItem('textColor');
                var backgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('bgColor');



    document.getElementById('banner').style.color = textColor;
        document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor; 

                }


                checkBanner();

            </script>
</html>
```